# Is there any way (perhaps some kind of hack) to ignore specific errors/warnings in Firebug?

Tags: firefox

As a web developer I use Firebug constantly, and I've had just about enough of these persistent errors/warnings that always show up no matter what.  One of them is the "The Components object is deprecated" error (which should be a warning) and the other is "Exposing chrome JS objects to content without **exposedProps_** is insecure and deprecated".

I've taken a screen shot of the three items I get all the time no matter:  http://snaps.vertigofx.com/009/snap1330_2013-03-27_06.54.41.png

Sometimes I get other errors/warnings, too, and like the ones I already mentioned they are not related to anything I am working on, so I just have to try to ignore them.  However no matter how "used to them" I may think I be, when I see that red text I automatically think I've broken something and it just bugs me.

I just recently upgraded Firefox to 19.0.2.  Before that the errors/warnings were even worse, but they're still not gone.  I've found one forum thread on the internet regarding the "Components object" one and the original poster said he got it to go away but wasn't specific enough on what that was.

Anyway, if anybody knows what I can do to rid myself of these, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Why not resolve these errors and warnings? Have you checked the referenced pages and see what you're doing wrong on your JS?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, these errors and warnings have nothing to do with my code or my work.  They appear on any and every page, including here at Stack Overflow.  The referenced "pages" are local files that are part of Firefox or Firebug itself.

Comment: That's disconcerting. Are you using any add-on that may have triggered those errors? I can't repro those using clean Firefox install + Firebug.

Comment: I thought it might be Greasemonkey (the most likely culprit), but I disabled it and the errors still appear.  Although, I didn't FULLY disable the addon completely, I simply deactivated it via the icon.  I'll go through and disable some addons and see if the problem goes away.